# Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release

Tags: momentjs, ionic2

I am using `Moments` but get a **depreciation** warning. Can anyone advise where my code is causing this, and what it should change to please?

http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:101533:106)
    at configFromString (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103263:33)
    at configFromInput (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103623:14)
    at prepareConfig (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103606:14)
    at createFromConfig (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103573:45)
    at createLocalOrUTC (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103660:17)
    at local__createLocal (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103664:17)
    at utils_hooks__hooks (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:101264:30)
    at DateFormatPipe.transform (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:115304:17)
    at DebugAppView._View_MessagesPage3.detectChangesInternal (MessagesPage.template.js:795:88)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:16171:15)
```

**messages.html**

```
<center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
<span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
```

**messages.ts**

```
import {DateFormatPipe} from 'angular2-moment';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/messages/messages.html',
  pipes: [DateFormatPipe]
})
```

**models.d.ts**

```
  interface Message {
    _id?: string;
    chatId?: string;
    senderId?: string;
    ownership?: string;
    content?: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    changeDate?: boolean;
    readByReceiver?: boolean;
    lastMessageComp?: Tracker.Computation;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "createdAt" property contains a string and not a date. Is the object retrieved from server? if it is, most probably you have a date formatted to text (something like "2012-04-21T18:25:43" or "\"\/Date(1335205592410)\/\"").

Please remember that with typescript you can specify the types of the variables, type-checking is performed at "compile time", but it is not guarantee that the content is a date when the transpiled ts is executed by the browser (and also, you can apply a pipe to a string property without any "compile time" errors).

If the object is a json deserialized from http, what you can do is manually parse the date:

```
return this.http.get('api/Some/Url/Messages', { search: params })
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let messages = res.json();

            return _.map(messages, (t: Message) => {
                return {
                    chatId: t.chatId,
                    senderId: t.senderId,
                    ...: ...,
                    createdAt: moment(t.createdAt, 'YYYYMMDD').toDate(),
                    ...: ...
                };
            });
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't think that's the answer, because the `createdAt` always just comes from the MongoDB and is defined as: `createdAt?: Date;`, I never manipulate the date, except when adding it to the MongoDB, with `new Date()`.

Comment: ps. I will try add it into MongoDB like this:  `moment(new Date())`

Comment: Can't add a `Moment` to a `Date`:  `error TS2345: Argument of type '{ memberIds: string[]; lastMessageCreatedAt: Moment; read: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Chat'.`  I think I neet to retrieve it like that rather.

Comment: Ok, it comes from MongoDB, but to be rendered by the browser the data will be serialized to json and deserialized to js object when you use http (or you are using angular universal or anything else?)
When this serialization/deserialization occurs, the date is a string because JSON doesn't support date natively.
Please, try to use Augury chrome plugin to understand the type of your CreatedAt value